# Laravel eloquent: HasManyThrough of HasManyThrough relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is this possible?

Relationship:
Category hasMany CategoryBoards
CategoryBoards hasMany threads
CategoryBoards hasMany threadPosts THROUGH threads

Visual Relationship:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvSnl.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4RCG.jpg

I want to get the # of threads and thread posts of categories.

On my category, I can count threads because of the threads relationship.
However for threadposts, I don't know how I would relate it with categories. I tried something below but it doesn't work.

```
//CATEGORY CLASS

    public function threads() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\Views\ThreadView',
        'App\Models\Views\CategoryBoardView',
        'categoryId',
        'categoryBoardId',
        'categoryId',
        'categoryBoardId'
    );
}

//doesnt work
public function threadPosts() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\Views\ThreadPostView',
        $this->threads(),
        'categoryBoardId',
        'threadId',
        'categoryId',
        'threadId'
    );
}
```

My query currently looks like this:

```
            $returnData['categories'] = CategoryView::with('categoryBoards')
            ->withCount('threads AS threadCount')
            ->get();
```

Comment: I get confused with so many relationships, could you add code from migrations, so we can see at all fields and what possible relationships you can make

Comment: Added an image.

Comment: you need to add a model CategoryBoards where you will put the function threadPosts that get the thread posts through threads

Comment: I already have those.

Comment: You can't go 4 classes deep with hasmanythrough, but you can count the forth level, like @vpalade mentioned, why do you need the forth level is the question?

Comment: The answer of @vplade doesn't work. That was actually my first approach, but found out that you cannot count eager loaded relationship.

Comment: I'm making a forum and in the home page where the categories is displayed, I also want to know how many threads and threadPosts are there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$returnData['categories'] = CategoryView::with(['categoryBoards' => function($q){
                 $q->withCount('threadPosts');
            }])
            ->withCount('threads AS threadCount')                
            ->get();
```

The `threadPosts` relationship will be in `CategoryBoards` Model

`threadPosts_count` should be in each `categoryBoards` object

Comment: ->withCount('categoryBoards.threadPosts AS threadPostsCount') This doesn't work. I think you cannot count eager loaded relationship.

Comment: Can you show in the question the controllers and relationships

Comment: Hi, I put ->withCount('threads AS threadCount') in the closure and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$returnData['categories'] = CategoryView::with(['categoryBoards' => function($query) {
        $query->withCount(['threads AS threadCount', 'threadPosts AS threadPostCount']);
    }])->get();
```

Credits to @vplade